# Why is the mouseenter part of this hover executing, but not the mouseleave?

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseevent

I am using [this syntax option](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#example-1) for jquery hover.

Here is my code:

```
$('mySelector')
    .hover(
        function(){
            $(this).html('<img src="images/myImage2.png" height="23" width="24" />');
        },
        function(){
            $(this).html('<img src="images/myImage1.png" height="23" width="24" />');
        }
    );
```

The original text for the element referenced by mySelector is the mouseleave option - `$(this).html('<img src="images/myImage1.png" height="23" width="24" />');`

The first handler, for mouseenter/mouseover, is working correctly. But the second handler, for mouseleave/mouseout (which should restore the original image), never executes. When I trace it in firebug, the mouseover event is triggered, but the second "function()" is not reached.

**Edit:**

For clarity, my html code is something like this:

```
<div id="results">
   <span class="imageClass"><img src="images/myImage1.png" height="23" width="24" /</span>
</div>
```

And then my selector is `"#results .imageClass"`

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue on jsfiddle?

Comment: Check the fiddle I have posted

Comment: @zerkms - I can't seem to get on to jsfiddle right now, when I do I'll try to reproduce it.

Comment: @froadie Can you post the HTML structure for all the relevant elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this problem could be that the element which **triggered** the `mouseenter` event (i.e. the `<img>` node) is removed from the DOM before it can trigger the `mouseleave` event. The event is caught and handled by `mySelector`'s event handler, but the `<img>` is the actual source of the event. It would therefore make sense that the `mouseleave` event is not triggered by the new `<img>`, because the mouse never entered it in the first place.

To clarify: the DOM node to which the event handler is bound (`mySelector`) is not the same as the node which first triggers the event (the `<img>`). Because the `<img>` has no handler of its own for this event, the event will [bubble up through the DOM tree](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation) until it encounters a node which does (in this case, `mySelector`).

It turns out that [adeneo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11411151/990877) does work, despite the fact that his/her answer was inaccurate. Here is a working example: **[jsbin.com/ikolog](http://jsbin.com/ikolog/edit)**.

Helpful resources:

- [DOM Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM_Client_Object_Cross-Reference/DOM_Events) (MDN)
- [Event Propagation Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation) (MDN)
- How to [Stop Event Propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/More_Event_Handlers#Stop_Event_Propagation) (MDN)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will try this and let you know. But why is the "element which triggered the mouseenter event removed from the DOM"? It's not the image that's triggering the event, it's the span around it.

Comment: @froadie: it's true that the event is _handled_ by the `<span>`, but the actual origin of the event - the element which triggered it - it most likely the `<img>`. Since the `<img>` has no handler for the event, the event "bubbles" up through the DOM until it encounters an element which does. Have a look at the [MDN docs on DOM events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM_Client_Object_Cross-Reference/DOM_Events).

Comment: Thank you, this does fix the problem! However, if the issue is what you say it is, why was my mouseenter event being triggered even after the original img tag was removed?

Comment: (and thanks for the "his/her" :) why does everyone always assume programmers are hes? ;) )

Comment: @froadie: like I said, the event hander was still bound to the `<span>`. That much doesn't change, so the new `<img>` will trigger another `mouseenter` event (one of its own), which will (again) be caught by the `<span>`'s event handler. And again, the `<img>` will be removed from the DOM, making it unable to trigger the `mouseleave` event.

Comment: I know plenty of great programmers who happen to be female. In fact, [the world's first programmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_Lovelace) was a woman. I think it's just the there-are-no-women-on-the-intarwebs syndrome.

Answer (score 1):

You're replacing the entire element, and the new element has no event handler bound and won't work with your hover function because it's not the same element you originally bound, try:

```
$('mySelector').hover(function(){
        $('img', this).prop('src', 'images/myImage2.png');
    },
    function(){
        $('img', this).prop('src', 'images/myImage1.png');
    }
);
```

Or if that's not an option, delegate the event by using `on()`

Comment: He's replacing the **content** of the element being hovered, not the element itself, so I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: As @AnthonyGrist says, this can't be the issue - the mouseover event is triggered multiple times (observed using firebug), each time I hover over.

Comment: Although your answer is wrong (the event handler is not lost or replaced), your solution does [fix the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11412148/990877).

Answer (score -1):

I agreed with PPvG, who states in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11412148/19679):

> the reason for this problem is that the element which triggered the mouseenter event (i.e. the  node) is removed from the DOM. The event bubbles up the DOM to mySelector, where it is caught and handled, but the  is the source of the event. It would therefore make sense that the mouseleave event is not triggered by the new  (the mouse never entered it in the first place).

Therefore, as a solution, you may use `.attr('src','full_url_here')`. adeneo suggests the following code in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11411151/19679):

```
$('#myImg').hover(function()
    {
        $(this).attr("src","http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/dellios_system_icons/png_128/css-grey.png");
    },
    function(){
        $(this).attr("src","http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/dellios_system_icons/png_128/css.png");
    }
);
```

Additional HTML code for this:

```
<div id="mySelector">
    <img id="myImg" src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/dellios_system_icons/png_128/css.png" />
</div>
```

Finally, a demo: http://jsbin.com/elofoc/7/edit#preview

Comment: It is a correct selector. Which is why the mouseover event on it is working.

Comment: What is `mySlector` an id of an element or a class of an element? It is better if you provide your HTML having `mySelector`. So we could analyze it better.

Comment: Did you just copy the correct bits from the other two answers? =/

Comment: @PPvG - I edited the answer to make the attribution a little more clear. It's fine to quote from other answers to make a better overall one, but you need to show where you drew information from. I think this now gives proper credit where it is due.